# Storing Images in Firebase with Authentication ID- Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-storage

I am able to save images into my firebase storage but then, in the storage, there is nothing to tell me the id of the user who uploaded the photo. In my app, users can upload photos for blogs and as much as that is concerned, every photo updated should have the id of the user and also an the key of the blog respectively. So it would be easy for me to fetch the images respectively for each blog. How can i achieve this?

This is how i save my images

```
 public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetType("image/*");
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionPick);
            StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Image"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            try{
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(this.ContentResolver, data.Data);
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg,100,stream);
                    byte[] array = stream.ToArray();

                    imageViewDrop.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);


                }

                if(data.Data != null){
                     pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
                   pd.SetTitle("Uploading");
                    pd.Show();

                    StorageReference images = storageRef.Child("images");

                    images.PutFile(data.Data).AddOnSuccessListener(this);
                    images.PutFile(data.Data).AddOnProgressListener(this);
                }


                else {

                }


                imageViewDrop.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception e){

            }


        }


        public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            pd.Dismiss();
        }

        public void OnProgress(Java.Lang.Object snapshot)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use user's `Uid` to create a reference in storage for each user.

I assume your `storageRef` in `StorageReference images = storageRef.Child("images");` means `FirebaseStorage.Instance.Reference`, then firstly, check the current user like this:

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.CurrentUser;
```

If user is null, of course we need to authenticate, but if it is not null, create an user reference first then under this reference create your "images" or "blogs" and so on... For example:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.Instance;
//create child reference
StorageReference storageRef = storage.Reference;

var userRef = storageRef.Child(user.Uid);
var imageRef = userRef.Child("images");
```